# Consume Web Service with soap:mustUnderstand attribute

Tags: c#, xml, soap

This is my sample Code for Web service. I'm new to SOAP application if someone can spot any problem here it's much appreciated. This  error only happened  if mustUnderstand attribute  ="1"

```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.xxxx.co.uk/Integration/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class ADNHeaderContact : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public MyHeader myHeader;


        [WebMethod]
        [SoapHeader("myHeader")]

        public string HelloWorld()
        {

            XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
            using (Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
            {
                receiveStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader readStream =
                                       new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
                }
            }


            using (XmlBreaker readxml = new XmlBreaker())
            {
                using (ReponseSaveApplications respose = new ReponseSaveApplications())
                {

                    return ("Hello");


                }

            };
        }

    }
```

My Postman  post request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
     <MyHeader soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns="http:www.xxxx.co.uk/Integration/">
      <MyValue>string</MyValue>
    </MyHeader>
  </soap:Header
  <soap:Body>
    <HelloWorld xmlns="http://www.xxxx.co.uk/Integration/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Postman post response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: SOAP header MyHeader was not understood.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderHandling.SetHeaderMembers(SoapHeaderCollection headers, Object target, SoapHeaderMapping[] mappings, SoapHeaderDirection direction, Boolean client)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

> [SoapHeader.MustUnderstand Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader.mustunderstand(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> When an XML Web service client adds a SOAP header to an XML Web
> service method call with the MustUnderstand property set to true, the
> XML Web service method must set the DidUnderstand property to true;
> otherwise, a SoapHeaderException is thrown back to the XML Web service
> client by ASP.NET.